# asp.net mvc 4 - how to generate crystal reports in mvc 4 using Entity Framework -> stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I have to generate reports using stored procedure with passing input values to the procedure. in asp.net mvc 4,How can I achieve this?
I'm using entity framework also.so i have to do this using entity framework stored procedure.

i haven't find any useful tutorial regarding this one.
Currently i'm doing db first.

I can easily do this for standalone project c# but i havent done this for asp.net mvc project.

i did one of my project by creating data set and generate .xsd after design crystal report then load data using data set.i did this for asp.net project.

Right now actually i want to do this using stored procedure.
please let me know if there are any better mechanism to do this.
but i want to go with stored procedure.

Comment: Do you want to show crystal report on website, or you want the reports to be run on server by the web admin etc..

Comment: i want to run on web site. actually i'm building e ticketing web site.after client do some purchase i need to give him receipt/invoice.
i cannot found any free reporting things for asp.net mvc so i moved to crystal report.

Comment: This is a website, you need to send an email as a confirmation. If they need it by paper then you will have a backend application that generate a paper invoice and send it by post. if you want to present something they can't change then you can use pdf